# My cursor movement is laggy and stutters

Tags: fedora, kde, mouse, cursor

My cursor movement is very laggy and stutters a lot.

```
OS: Fedora Linux 35 (KDE Plasma) x86_64 
Kernel: 5.14.10-300.fc35.x86_64 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: Plasma 5.24.4 
CPU: Intel i5-7300HQ (4) @ 3.500GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630 
Memory: 5682MiB / 15883MiB
```

I have checked out the following links but they were not helpful in my case.
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/qavdfd/is_mouse_lagging_common_in_kde/

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/choppy-stuttering-mouse-and-graphics/4299

Answer (score 1):

Usually the open source drivers for nvidia (nouveau) are not very good.
Check what drivers are being used, then try installing the proprietary.

You can check by running

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Comment: ```00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)```. Should I reinstall it?

Comment: Is there no way to get nouveau to work properly? I use a custom kernel and no initramfs and the proprietary drivers are a huge PITA, so that's not an option for me.